# What is the alternative to str.translate in python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using the following function to remove numbers from filenames.

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\X\Downloads\Compressed\prank\prank")
##    print(file_list)
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\X\Downloads\Compressed\prank\prank")
    print(os.getcwd())
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "1234567890"))        

rename_files()
```

It works perfectly in python 2, but in python 3 it throws the following error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\rename_files.py", line 11, in <module>
    rename_files()
  File "C:\Python34\rename_files.py", line 9, in rename_files
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "1234567890"))
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

How to solve this problem without using regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.translate` still exists in Python 3, it's just used differently (though it matches `unicode.translate` from Py2). `maketrans` is now a static method of `str` (and `bytes`), and deletion of characters for `str.maketrans` is handled through the same lookup table use for translations.

For your case, one time up front you'd do:

```
deletedigits = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys("1234567890"))
```

then perform the translation with:

```
file_name.translate(deletedigits)
```

Note that there are other ways to accomplish this, e.g.:

```
# ifilterfalse on Py2
''.join(itertools.filterfalse(str.isdigit, file_name))
```

or:

```
''.join(let for let in file_name if not let.isdigit())
```

Comment: You can use as follows:

    import re
    import glob
    file_path_list = glob.glob("D:\*")
    #Here We get List Of All Files in given directory, you can specify also to get specific type .html or .xls
    #eg. you can write to get html files to replace html file name only, l = glob.glob("D:\*.html")  


    for Fpath in file_path_list:
        dir = os.path.dirname(Fpath )
        fname =  Fpath.strip(dir)
        name = os.path.splitext(fname)
        fn = re.sub('[\d]','',name[0])
        os.rename(Fpath, dir+fn+name[1])